# How to create type Void array in C# Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In creating a level populator for my game, I created an array for my cube prefabs and made separate voids for each cube position so that each cube is randomised to a separate output from others (not putting separate voids just randomises the cubes to all be one colour at run time). I can make it work by creating separate voids for each object instance, but I want to know if it's possible to create a void array. Currently I get an error of unexpected [, ) in class/struct as well as primary constructor body not allowed.

Previous following of various tutorials only randomised the cubes to one colour at run time. I put the positions in an array and am not sure what to do with slot.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class testlevelscript : MonoBehaviour {
public GameObject[] blocks;
public int currentBlock;

void Start () {

    //function instance
    int[] slot = new[] {
        1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        Instantiate (slot [i] ());
                ;
        //slot[i]();
    }

    //position list
    Vector3[] position = new[] {
        new Vector3 (0, 0, 0), 
        new Vector3 (1, 0, 0), 
        new Vector3 (2, 0, 0),
        new Vector3 (3, 0, 0), 
        new Vector3 (4, 0, 0), 
        new Vector3 (-1, 0, 0),
        new Vector3 (-2, 0, 0), 
        new Vector3 (-3, 0, 0), 
        new Vector3 (-4, 0, 0),
        new Vector3 (-5, 0, 0)};
    Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.identity;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        currentBlock = Random.Range (0, blocks.Length);
    Instantiate (blocks [currentBlock], position [i], rotation);
        }
    }

void slot[i] () {
    currentBlock = Random.Range (0, blocks.Length);
    Instantiate (blocks [currentBlock], position[i], rotation);
}
}
```

Currently I have the script working manually, just want to see if it's possible to put it in some arrays to make it more efficient.

Comment: Where do you create a void? I don´t understand what you actually want to achieve. Do you want to call `Istantiate` 10 times?

Comment: Are you sure the word void is the one you mean? Im surprised it lets you instantiate the 0 integer an let you call it as a method

Comment: @ HimBromBeere I want to instantiate a void (or some type of function) 10 times

Comment: @BugFinder I'm not sure if void is correct, but I created a function in my manual script and called it and it worked. Doesn't the count start from zero, so if you call zero it's calling the first method from the list?

Comment: If you want to run something 10 times you dont need instantiate